# Replicate changes on some tables in two separate databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We need to have two identical web applications (warehouse management) for two different geographical markets.
We need to be able to move products from one database to the other according to the shipments that will be made between the two locations.

Up to this point there are no problems.

However, we would like to have the possibility to make changes to some tables (users, products, support tables) only on the main app/database and to automatically replicate these changes on the second database where the possibility of modification and insertion will be disabled.

Is there a way to manage the mirroring of only some tables between two different databases?
Both databases are on the same server and are MS Sql Server Express.

Comment: Many options exist, Change Tracking, Change-Data-Capture, Triggers, Log Shipping etc,  although I couldn't say for sure any or all are supported in SQL Express edition.

Comment: Replication would be the first thing to come to mind but it's very fragile and breaks too fast. (I have worked with replication "experts" and these guys spend most of their time putting out fires, rather than expanding features.)
The simplest and most reliable solution in cases of read-only replication is  a MERGE 
 statement (or DELETE/INSERT INTO on older versions of SQL Server) that is exececuted in a SQL Agent Job. You can create a Linked Server and synonyms between the SQL Server instances. If you want more information, please drop a line and I'll give you a step-by-step answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.